# Import a callback from a class to an other in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'am using typescript 3.

I have this map component :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { any } from 'prop-types';
import {Coords} from 'google-map-react';
export interface HelloProps { center: Coords ; zoom: number ; }


const AnyReactComponent = ( {text} : { lat: any,text:any,lng:any}) => <div>{text}</div>;
export class SimpleMap extends React.Component <HelloProps, {}> {
  defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
  };
  myCallbackMap = (dataFromChild:number) => {
    this.defaultProps.zoom = dataFromChild;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AIzaSyDs5u7u1Almh8-Jch3cHzuWB-egVPTZajs' }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text="My Marker"
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SimpleMap;
```

And i want to use :

```
 myCallbackMap = (dataFromChild:number) => {
    this.defaultProps.zoom = dataFromChild;
  }
```

In my search bar so when someone search it change the map.

Here is my search file  (scroll down to see the call) :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Suggestions from './Suggestions'
import myCallbackMap from './Map'
const API_KEY:string = "process.env"
const API_URL:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1/test'

export class Search extends React.Component{
  state = {
  query: '' as string,
    results : [] as any[]
  }
  search = {
    value: '' as string,
    }
  getInfo = () => {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/${this.state.query}/`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data.data
        })
      })
  }

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
        if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.getInfo()
        }
      } else if (!this.state.query) {
      }
    })
  }
  myCallbackSearch = (dataFromChild:string) => {
    this.search.value = dataFromChild;
// here where i want ot use the map call back
    myCallbackMap(111);

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} callbackFromParentSearch={this.myCallbackSearch}/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Search
```

How to use and import properly the map call back and use it in the search component ? The main goal is that when someone type in the search bar it change the map dynamicaly. but now i'am working on a simple prototype.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import it because it would be a static function when you need an instance function.

You have to pass the callback as a prop of the search component.

The callback itself actually looks like an event handler which role is to change the default props (which should be declared static) of the google map in another component. So my guess is you don't actually want to change the default props of the map but rather give it a new zoom value via props.

You can either:

Implement the handler in the common ancestor to both the search and the map component, make the zoom a state of this common ancestor, update this state in the callback, and propagate through props the callback all the way to the search component, and the zoom value all the way to the map component.

Or:

Put this state in a redux store which will allow you to skip the props chaining and directly register map to listen for zoom change in the store, and pass an action creator to the search component so that it can notify the store when the search change.

**Common ancestor version:**

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Suggestions from './Suggestions'
    const API_KEY:string = "process.env"
    const API_URL:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1/test'

    export class Search extends React.Component{
      state = {
        query: '' as string,
        results : [] as any[]
      }
      search = {
        value: '' as string,
      }
      getInfo = () => {
        axios.post(`${API_URL}/${this.state.query}/`)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            this.setState({
              results: data.data
            })
          })
      }

      handleInputChange = () => {
        this.setState({
          query: this.search.value
        }, () => {
          if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
            if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
              this.getInfo()
            }
          } else if (!this.state.query) {
          }
        })
      }
      myCallbackSearch = (dataFromChild:string) => {
        this.search.value = dataFromChild;
    // here where i want ot use the map call back
        myCallbackMap(111);

      }
      render() {
        const { callbackFromParentSearch } = this.props;
        return (
          <form>
            <input
              placeholder="Search for..."
              ref={input => this.search = input}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <Suggestions results={this.state.results} callbackFromParentSearch={callbackFromParentSearch}/>
          </form>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Search;
```

Note that the components don't need to have the same exact parent below is just an example. It will still work if you pass the props from parent to child until you get to the targets Search and SimpleMap.

```
    export default class CommonAncestor extends Component {
        state: {
            zoom: 3 as number,
        }
        handleCallbackFromParentSearch = (dataFromChild:number) => {
            this.setState(() => ({ zoom: dataFromChild }));
        }
        render() {
            const { zoom } = this.state;
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Search callbackFromParentSearch={this.handleCallbackFromParentSearch} />
                    <SimpleMap zoom={zoom} />
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Redux version:**

Search component connected to the changeZoom action

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import Suggestions from './Suggestions';
    import { actionCreators as zoomAC } from 'src/redux/zoom';
    const API_KEY:string = "process.env"
    const API_URL:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/v1/test'

    class Search extends React.Component{
      state = {
        query: '' as string,
        results : [] as any[]
      }
      search = {
        value: '' as string,
      }
      getInfo = () => {
        axios.post(`${API_URL}/${this.state.query}/`)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            this.setState({
              results: data.data
            })
          })
      }

      handleInputChange = () => {
        this.setState({
          query: this.search.value
        }, () => {
          if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
            if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
              this.getInfo()
            }
          } else if (!this.state.query) {
          }
        })
      }
      myCallbackSearch = (dataFromChild:string) => {
        this.search.value = dataFromChild;
    // here where i want ot use the map call back
        myCallbackMap(111);

      }
      render() {
        const { changeZoom} = this.props;
        return (
          <form>
            <input
              placeholder="Search for..."
              ref={input => this.search = input}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <Suggestions results={this.state.results} callbackFromParentSearch={changeZoom}/>
          </form>
        )
      }
    }

    export default connect(
        null,
        dispatch => ({
            changeZoom: value => dispatch(zoomAC.changeZoom(value))
        })
    )(Search);
```

SimpleMap component connected to the zoom store:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { any } from 'prop-types';
    import {Coords} from 'google-map-react';
    export interface HelloProps { center: Coords ; zoom: number ; }


    const AnyReactComponent = ( {text} : { lat: any,text:any,lng:any}) => <div>{text}</div>;
    export class SimpleMap extends React.Component <HelloProps, {}> {
      defaultProps = {
        center: {
          lat: 59.95,
          lng: 30.33
        },
        zoom: 11
      };
      render() {
        return (
          // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
          <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
            <GoogleMapReact
              bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AIzaSyDs5u7u1Almh8-Jch3cHzuWB-egVPTZajs' }}
              defaultCenter={this.props.center}
              defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
            >
              <AnyReactComponent
                lat={59.955413}
                lng={30.337844}
                text="My Marker"
              />
            </GoogleMapReact>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default connect(
        state => ({ zoom: state.zoom })
    )(SimpleMap);
```